# Why running LSTM inside for loop produces different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to run LSTM inside a loop to find the optimal parameters.

I tried to fix the model parameters(number of units,window_size, epochs..etc) inside the loop to check if it is working fine but I realized that only the first run produces accurate results.
Then results are varying after executing it multiple times inside the loop

I am not sure if I need to clear or reset the model after each round.
I tried to google it and tried `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` but it did not work. In each round, I need to destroy the previous model and create new one from scratch.

```
# LSTM Model
model_name = Sequential()
model_name.add(LSTM(num_units_optimized, activation='relu', input_shape=(look_back_optimized, n_features_selected)))
model_name.add(Dense(look_ahead*4, 'relu'))
model_name.add(Dense(look_ahead*2, 'relu'))
model_name.add(Dense(look_ahead))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(clipnorm=5)
model_name.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse', metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])
```

here are my imports:

```
seed = 42 # Here sd means seed.

import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed)

import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(seed)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError

#EVALUATE
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by rounds you mean epochs?

Comment: No, I mean each run in the loop ..

Comment: Where is your code for LSTM inside the for-loop?